# I am having problems with converting a taylor polynomial into mathematica

Tags: series-expansion

So I am doing a project that requires us to convert problems into mathematica

I am doing a Taylor polynomial 
the problem is:
Taylor Polynomial 10() for the function () centered at the number . Graph () and 10() on
the same xy-plane between −10 ≤  ≤ 10. Use the Taylor Polynomial to find the y-value when x = 2 and
compare that with the actual y-value for () when x = 2.

i know the input is 
ln(x+2) centered at a =2
and the answer is 
[image: Answer to the problem]

but the problem is i dont know how to code a taylor poly. i have searched all around and found answers kind of but it is hard to understand what they are doing. 
please help

Comment: are you sure you want to plot log(x) for negative x values?

Comment: Look up `Series[]` and `Normal[]`.

Answer (score 1):

May be can use this to get you started.

[image]

```
Manipulate[

 Module[{T10, , x},
  T10 = Normal[Series[Log[x + 2], {x, a, nTerms}]];

  Plot[{T10, Log[x + 2]}, {x, 0, 10},
   Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"f(x)", None}, {"x", 
      "Comparing function to its Taylor series at point"}},
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large],  Point[{a, 0}]},
   BaseStyle -> 14,
   GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
   PlotRange -> All,
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
   PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
  ],

 {{a, 2, "Epxansion point?"}, .1, 5, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{nTerms, 4, "how many terms?"}, 1, 20, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {a, nTerms}
 ]
```